# AspectJ Weaver & java module system (spring + gradle), problem with compilation

Tags: java, spring, gradle, aspectj

I use spring 5, Java 10 and Gradle 4.8

I face the following issue:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable`

I read on the stack overflow to add:

`compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.1'`

However when I do this, I get 100 errors like:

`error: module java.persistence reads package org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect from both aspectjrt and org.aspectj.weaver`

How to fix the issue?

Dependencies:

```
compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.5'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '5.0.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.1'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.0.8.RELEASE'
compile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.1.8.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'

compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.1.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-hikaricp', version: '5.3.1.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.10.Final'
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.1-b08'
compile group: 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine', name: 'caffeine', version: '2.6.2'

compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.1'
compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.28'
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'
compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
```

Comment: Please post your `dependencies` block of `build.gradle`

Comment: @caco3 done, see edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that spring-data-jpa has dependency of aspectjrt version 1.8.x which (as I suppose) is not ready for java9 modularity. I excluded it from dependencies and included proper versions of both aspectjrt and weaver and it works now.